# Redirecting old anchor links to new anchor links

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, anchor

I'm overhauling a website that someone else built for my organization. It was originally set up with "not so great" anchor links which included spaces. I have replaced those anchors with new ones that will work better.

Example:
One of the old anchors looked like this `/course/#To Have` which browsers would luckily convert to `/course/#To%20Have`. I changed that anchor to this: `/course/#to-have`.

I'm now wanting to make sure that any anchors that may have been shared on social media or that could be linked to from other websites still work; I was planning on doing this via redirect in the .htaccess file, such as this one:

`Redirect 301 /course/#To%20Have /course/#to-have`

After some research I've found that this is not possible due to the `#` in the URLs. And I also have not seen examples where an anchor was redirected to another anchor.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, this is not possible with `.htaccess`. You could, however, use JavaScript to convert the hash values and redirect. Or, better yet, use JavaScript to convert and then simply find the element (using the converted value) to scroll to - this prevents a redirect, which I think is not necessary in this case.

Comment: Thank you Mike. Can you tell me more about this? I'm not sure how I would accomplish what you're suggesting.

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, this is not possible with `.htaccess`.

Reason being: the hash part (known as the *fragment*) is not actually sent to the server, and so Apache would not be able to pick it up. Servers may only pick up everything before that, which is described in the Syntax section of [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator#Syntax).

As an alternative, I would recommend that you use JavaScript to convert the fragment before scrolling to its location. You can do that by pulling in the value of `[window.]location.hash` (the part in square parenthises is optional as `location` is also available in the global scope) if it exists, as shown below:

```js
if (window.location.hash) {

    // Function to 'slugify' the fragment
    // @see https://gist.github.com/mathewbyrne/1280286#gistcomment-1606270

    var slugify = function(input) {
        return input.toString().toLowerCase().trim()
            .replace(/\s+/g, '-')           // Replace spaces with -
            .replace(/&/g, '-and-')         // Replace & with 'and'
            .replace(/[^\w\-]+/g, '')       // Remove all non-word chars
            .replace(/\-\-+/g, '-');        // Replace multiple - with single -
    }

    // Now get the hash and 'slugify' it

    var hash = slugify(window.location.hash.split('#')[1]);

    // Go to the new hash by setting it

    window.location.hash = '#' + hash;

}
```

Comment: Thank you Mike. So for my example above, is this what I'd do for the last two lines?

`var hash = slugify(window.location.hash.split('/course/#To%20Have')[1]);
    window.location.hash = '/course/#to-have' + hash;`

And I'm also wondering where I would put this javascript? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You need not change any of the code - this is automatic as it fetches the current fragment, converts it to the new format you are using, and then scrolls to view. I would recommend putting this somewhere in your `<head>`.

Comment: Thank you Mike. I managed to put this javascript into the head (I can see it in the source code of the site now)! Yay! However, when the "redirect" happens from the old anchor to the new one, the page doesn't scroll down to the correct position (the actual location of the anchor id). Is this javascript supposed to be able to scroll to the location of the anchor?

Comment: It should do so automatically when the hash is set (the last line). Perhaps try moving the script tag down to just above `</body>` - that should fix it. Alternatively, wrap the code in `$(function() { <put the code here> })` if you are using jQuery.

Comment: Ah, it's working now without making any more changes! Simply added your code, wrapped in `add_action('wp_head','hook_javascript'); function hook_javascript() { $output="<script> code </script>"; echo $output; }` into my child theme functions.php file. Thank you!